# Debezium Oracle schema.include.list don't work

Tags: oracle, filter, schema, debezium

We are using Debezium 1.9.4-Final to capture the changes and send it to ElasticSearch.
It is working, but there's one thing that's intrigued me.
We set the ***schema.include.list*** to filter only the schema that we expect the changes to be captured, but when we start the connector, the log shows that the hole database is been scanned and added to the ***database.server.name*** topic that is created. The database is huge, so it takes a lot of time to really starting capture the only table that we set to be captured.

This part configuration is like that:

```
database.server.name: server_name 
database.dbname: server_name.database
table.include.list: ATBSCH.TB_DROP
schema.include.list: ATBSCH
```

Is there a way to make Debezium only watch the schema said in the schema.include.list attribute?

Comment: I have the same problem... have you found the solution? Debezium was not doing this in 1.8.

Comment: No, I didn't. Sorry for the late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation, I have found the solution to my problem. I think it was the same as yours. Set the following:

> debezium.source.database.history.store.only.captured.tables.ddl=true

The documentation for it: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.9/connectors/oracle.html#oracle-property-database-history-store-only-captured-tables-ddl